# gazebo crashes immediately using roslaunch after installing gazebo ros packages

Tags: ros

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hello,

after installing everything properly I am following the tutorials to test the tools (using groovy, gazebo 1.9 and gazebo_ros_pkgs).
I have a problem using roslaunch to start gazebo following this tutorial

http://gazebosim.org/wiki/Tutorials/1.9/Using_roslaunch_Files_to_Spawn_Models

when I want to start with  command roslaunch gazebo_ros willowgarage_world.launch
gazebo crashes after one sec and I get this error:

```
[gazebo_gui-3] process has died [pid 15649, exit code 139, cmd /home/usr/catkin_ws/src/gazebo_ros_pkgs/gazebo_ros/scripts/gzclient __name:=gazebo_gui __log:=/home/shahed/.ros/log/8981441a-03ea-11e3-8d2b-0017c4a8146b/gazebo_gui-3.log].
log file: /home/usr/.ros/log/8981441a-03ea-11e3-8d2b-0017c4a8146b/gazebo_gui-3*.log
```

this problem happens with all  world files( mud_world.launch,  shapes_world.launch,  rubble_world.launch), except the empty and willowgarage_world, both of them can be started using roslaunch tool but not always from the first attempt. Mostly from the second try.

I also followed “Creating a Custom World File” in the same tutorial and still the same problem occurred.

Any help plz!

Thanks in advance.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/4153/gazebo-crashes-immediately-using-roslaunch-after-installing-gazebo-ros-packages/) by [Zahra](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/320/zahra/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 122 on 2013-08-13

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hello

I followed this approach :

first, start with . ~/catkin_ws/devel/setup.bash . Then killall gzserver even if there is no process running and then roslaunch package[name] launch file[name].

Most of the time it works and if it doesnt just wait about 3 minutes before starting again , I still dont know why this is happening but after doing the above steps I am able to run my simulation with roslaunch from first or second attempt.

Hope it is helpful!

---

Originally posted by [Zahra](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/320/zahra/) with karma: 122 on 2013-08-23

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Shehzi](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/417/shehzi/) on 2013-09-22**:
Hi, killall gzserver worked for me. Thank you!

**Comment by [Zahra](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/320/zahra/) on 2013-09-22**:
Great, if the problem is constant you can try this way, it worked better for me. http://answers.gazebosim.org/question/4252/gazebo_gui-3-error-when-starting-gazebo-with/

**Comment by [mkelly66](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/14013/mkelly66/) on 2019-07-24**:
I was having a similar problem, but with
"roslaunch turtlebot3_gazebo turtlebot3_empty_world.launch".
Your solution worked for me!  Thanks, so much!

**Comment by [desmond13](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/8998/desmond13/) on 2020-11-25**:
This did not work for me :(

Answer (score 0):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

The problem is that roslaunch secretly adds two hidden arguments when starting up a node's executable: _name and _log.  If you are calling an executable through roslaunch that is not ROS interoperable, then that executable may fail at startup because it doesn't know how to handle the _name and _log arguments.  This is the case here, since roslaunch is actually calling a script file (rungazebo), which is a script that executes the "gazebo" command while passing in all arguments from roslaunch.  Gazebo doesn't know how to handle the _name and _log arguments so it dies.

---

Originally posted by [pcdangio](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/257/pcdangio/) with karma: 207 on 2016-02-16

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [yah130s](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1228/yah130s/) on 2016-07-23**:
Minor correction; `__name` and `__log`, I guess double underscore instead of single.

**Comment by [yah130s](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1228/yah130s/) on 2016-07-23**:
Your explanation sounds like that Gazebo processes should always die when they are called from `roslaunch`? There are number of successful .launch files out there so I think that's not the case.